# The specified directory could not be created

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We are migrating ColdFusion 9 code to ColdFusion 2016. We have set up the server and the application is working fine. The only issue we are facing for a long time is when we configure a shared path, and upload any file from the front end, we are getting below error. The website is hosted in IIS10 and the share path is configured in virtual directory converted to application. Is this because of obsolete tags?

> **Error Occurred While Processing Request**
>
> The specified directory //g0265/files$/files/tempupload/temp2955/
>   could not be created. The most likely cause of this error is that
>   //g0265/files$/files/tempupload/temp2955/ already exists on your file
>   system.
>
> The error occurred in D:/../../docs/insert.cfm:
>
> ```
> <cfdirectory name="checkdir" 
>   action="list" 
>   directory="#variables.uploadroot#" 
>   filter="#variables.randomelement#"> 
> <cfif checkdir.recordcount eq 0> 
>   <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#variables.uploaddir#"> 
> </cfif>
> ```

Comment: The website is hosted in IIS10 and the share path is configured in virtual directory converted to application.

Comment: The ColdFusion service must run as a user who is allowed to access the remote share

Comment: I tried changing the cf service to the service account which is used by share path ,but unable to add.I am getting access is denied error. Is there any alternative way

Comment: Hi Bernhard,  It worked..Thanks a lot

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - You should promote that comment to an answer.